# can't edit data with MYSQL WORKBENCH

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, mysql-workbench

I'm using **mysql workbench 6.3** on my Ubuntu 16.10. I'm trying to, as I do in other Mysql Management tools, to edit value of a field directly in **result grid**. I'm able to write the value in, but when I run the query again, I can see the value didn't save in the field. What was the problem?

[image]

Comment: thanks. you are right, I didn't click on the Apply button. I used to other management tools where you can just change the value and hit the enter or click away from the field, then the value is saved automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### MySQL Workbench - Committing table data modifications thru the GUI

**I'm able to write the value in, but when I run the query again, I can see the value didn't save in the field.**

When you update, delete, or insert data from the MySQL Workbench application, in order to "commit" those changes by default you have to press the <kbd>**`Apply`**</kbd> button.

Now when you run the query after this, you should see the updated data as expected.

[image]